# Call a function after a time gap In Angular JS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to refresh a page after showing a successfull message. I tied with many snippets but either it gets refreshed without showing message or vice-versa.

So I thought of Calling the Refresh function after an interval or Trigger again the button click event after some time to get the page refreshed.

Here is the code, How to achieve the above scenario?

#### JS CODE

```
$scope.Save = function (data) {
    debugger;
    $http.post($rootScope.WebApiURL + '/updatemanifeststatus');
    var value= $http.get($rootScope.WebApiURL + '/getmanifeststatus' );

        $scope.manifeststatus = data;

        $scope.showstatus = true;
        $scope.alert = { type: 'success', msg: 'Published Successfully.' };
        $(".statusDivPublish").show();

        $scope.Refresh1();

    }

    $scope.Refresh1 = function () {
        //refresh
        $state.go($state.current, {}, { reload: true });
    }
});
```

**HTML Button Call**

```
<div class="col-sm-offset-1">
    <button id="PublishButton" class="btn btn-default shiny " ng-disabled="manifeststatus.enablePublishButton" ng-click="Save(manifeststatus)">Publish</button>
</div>
```

What I want to do Here is Call the Refresh1() function after a time gap in such a way, the page gets refreshed after showing the message.

Comment: use `$state.reload` instead to fire `$scope.Refresh1` function. If you are using ui-router.

Comment: $timeout - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout

Comment: use a `toast` library if you only need to show some alert for a period. https://github.com/jirikavi/AngularJS-Toaster

Comment: Why do you need to reload? To refetch the data you just fetched? Besides that, you seem to be posting success messages when you obviously don't know whether your post operation has been a success or not. Plus you seem to be using jQuery and Angular to display messages.

Comment: @skubski so, what can be done exactly for this? I fetched the data. but its not getting displayed unless I do a manual refresh. So I want to refresh it in the code.

Comment: I answered with an example.

Answer (score 2):

I [plunkered](http://plnkr.co/edit/CrTC8B9IZ8cuRiXvEnld?p=preview) a bit on your problem and I did not need to use a `$timeout` to update the model with updated data.

```
.controller('AController', function(ptth$) {

    var self = this;

    self.time = 'wait for it';

    self.init = function() {
      ptth$.get().then(function(data) {
        self.time = data;
      });
    };

    self.init();

    self.save = function() {
        ptth$.post().then(function() {
          //I use an alert instead of a div we show or hide.
          window.alert('hey, this is real success');
          //You either re-fetch data here and update your model
          //Or you reload after the alert...

          //This example works with a ng-model update, instead of a reload
          self.init();
        }, function() {
          window.alert('this is failure');
        });
    };
})
```

Eventhough this is not the way I would set up things, this example should illustrate that you do not really need a `$timeout` or `$reload` for that matter.

Answer (score 1):

Inject $timeout and do this changes to your JS Code.

```
$scope.Save = function (data) {
    debugger;
    $http.post($rootScope.WebApiURL + '/updatemanifeststatus');
    var value= $http.get($rootScope.WebApiURL + '/getmanifeststatus' );

        $scope.manifeststatus = data;

        $scope.showstatus = true;
        $scope.alert = { type: 'success', msg: 'Published Successfully.' };
        $(".statusDivPublish").show();

        //Adding a 5 second delay
        $timeout($scope.Refresh1, 5000);

    }

    $scope.Refresh1 = function () {
        //refresh
        $state.go($state.current, {}, { reload: true });
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried your code, the page is getting refreshed with updated data but, the alert is not shown. The 3 lines after $scope.manifeststatus = data;

Comment: I believe the delay or $timeout is not working, because even if i give 10 sec delay. its executing as soon as I click the button.